# How to stop setInterval Timer with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using setInterval() with jquery to load and refresh Pictures from Webcam every 2 second as on this example :

```
$("cameralist").change(function(){
    $("cameralist option:selected").each(function(){
        var timer = setInterval(loadImage(), 2000); 

        function loadImage(){
            $("div.img").attr("src", URL); 
        }
    });
});
```

My Problem is, i want to clear the timer on every change event (every time new or other cameras are selected in the list) and restart the timer ...

How should i do this ? any idea ?

Comment: `clearInterval(timer)`?

Comment: First problem: `setInterval(loadImage(),2000);` will immediately invoke `loadImage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No jquery require, can use raw javascript

```
clearInterval(timer)
```

Use like so

```
$("cameralist").data().timer = null;

$("cameralist").change(function(){


  $("cameralist option:selected").each(function(){

       clearInterval($("cameralist").data().timer);
       $("cameralist").data().timer = setInterval(loadImage(),2000); 

       function loadImage(){

         $("div.img").attr("src", URL); 

       }
  });

});
```

If load of timers to clear

Use like so

```
$("cameralist").data().timers = [];

$("cameralist").change(function(){
  _.each($("cameralist").data().timers, function(timer) {
      setInterval(timer);
  });
  $("cameralist").data().timers = [];

  $("cameralist option:selected").each(function(){
       var timerRef = setInterval(loadImage(),2000); 
       $("cameralist").data().timers.push(timerRef);

       function loadImage(){

         $("div.img").attr("src", URL); 

       }
  });

});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval

Also great mind think alike :) +1 to person below

Comment: thanks aqm. that works but only one Timer will be cleared ! How to clear all Timers every time the cameralist will be selected ? (there are many timers started : one per selected camera)

Comment: ah well I'd use a array of timers and create a clearAllTimers function which would clear all the timers, then replace timer array with a new empty one, every time you create a new timer just push the timer into the array, ps i think you actually want setTimeout which is like setInterval but only fires once -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout

Answer (score 2):

> How to stop SetInterval Timer with Jquery

You don't. But you can do it with JavaScript:

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

You'll need to put your `timer` variable *outside* the `change` handler, though. I'd also set it to `0` initially (calling `clearInterval` with `0` is a no-op, so it's a handy initial value).

Also note that you're not setting up the interval correctly. This line:

```
var timer = setInterval(loadImage(),2000);
```

**calls** `loadImage` and passes its return value into `setInterval`, exactly like `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`. To refer to the function, remove the `()` after `loadImage`.

Something along these lines:

```
// Note: I'm assuming this code isn't at global scope. If it is, wrap it in a
// scoping function, we don't want or need `timer` to be global.
var timer = 0; // <== Initialize timer variable
$("cameralist").change(function () {

    $("cameralist option:selected").each(function () {

        clearInterval(timer); // <=== Clear previous timer if any
        timer = setInterval(loadImage, 2000); // <=== Set new timer
        // No () here ---------------^

        function loadImage() {
            $("div.img").attr("src", URL);
        }
    });
});
```

**But**, I don't see any reason to repeatedly set the `src` of an image to the same URL, unless that URL's content changes (and has caching disabled). If the content changes, keep using `setInterval`. If not, look at using `setTimeout` instead (it's a one-off timer, rather than a repeated one).

Comment: Thanks T.J. Crowder . im getting the Pictures from a servlet and the pictures must be changed every 2 seconds...

Answer (score 1):

It is not good idea to have a timer as a global variable.

```
/**
 * It is not good idea to have timer
 * as s global variable.
 */

$("cameralist").change((function (timer) {
    return function () {
        if (timer != null) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        $("cameralist option:selected").each(function () {
            timer = setInterval(loadImage, 2000);
            function loadImage() {
                $("div.img").attr("src", URL);
            }
        });
    }
})(null));
```